# how to set hostname using inventory file

Tags: ansible

I have my hosts in an inventory file as below:

```
cnamgw01b ansible_ssh_host=172.17.0.26 
cnamgw01a ansible_ssh_host=172.17.1.26
cnamgw02b ansible_ssh_host=172.17.0.23
cnamgw02a ansible_ssh_host=172.17.1.23 
cnamgw03a ansible_ssh_host=172.17.1.13
cnamgw03b ansible_ssh_host=172.17.0.13
```

These are new builds and I would like to set the hostname based on the inventory file.  I already have a script in place that updated the inventory file as new VM's are turned up and assigns a random hostname.  I would like to take this hostname assigned and set it as the hosts hostname.  How can I accomplish this?  Also note that I also use folders to subdivide the hosts by region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run something like this to set the system hostname to the inventory hostname:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: set system hostname
      command: hostnamectl set-hostname {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

That is, the variable `inventory_hostname` holds the name of the current host as it was named in your inventory.

This task assumes you have the `hostnamectl` command available. You could instead write the value of `inventory_hostname` to `/etc/hostname` and call the `hostname` command separately.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the ansible module `hostname` to set hostname.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/hostname_module.html

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Set hostname
    hostname:
     name: {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Comment: This is definitly the better answer and should be the accepted one. One should always prefer using existing modules over custom commands.

Comment: You need double quotes around the variable like this:
"{{ inventory_hostname }}"